# Visual Studio 2022 - не работает определение препроцессора в свойствах проекта

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю ?

Есть простейший код: в main вызывается функция в которой есть условие #ifdef.
Попытка указать определение препроцессора в свойствах проекта VS2022 - ни к чему не приводит, код который в теле #if - не "активируется". "Активируется" только при прямом указании #define.

Ниже сам код и скриншот проблемы:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_check.h"
 
 
int main()
{
my_check();
}
```

**my_check.cpp**

```
void my_check()
{
 
#ifdef my_MULTITHREAD
    std::cout << "my_MULTITHREAD" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "NOT my_MULTITHREAD" << std::endl;
#endif
 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю ?

Comment: `my_MULTITHREAD;` в начало списка добавляйте, а не в конец

Comment: @user7860670, ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! Работает. Но почему так ? Почему нужно в начало добавить ?

Comment: Потому что там идет `%(PreprocessorDefinitions)` который не факт, что имеет разделитель `;` в конце

Comment: Думаю, дело не в том, в начало или в конец, а в том, что разделитель там - `;`, а не `, `, который вы написали.